# jQuery Animation - fadeIn fadeOut images and titles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I must add statements to the JavaScript file that fade the caption and image out over a duration of one second. Also, I need to add a callback function to the statement that fades out the image when one is clicked.

I think my code should be working, but it does not do anything when in the browser. What am I doing wrong or is there another way to do this? Any suggestion are appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // preload images(given three lines)
        var swappedImage, imageCounter = 0, imageCache = [];
 $("#image_list a").each(function() {
            swappedImage = new Image();
            swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
            swappedImage.title = $(this).attr("title");
            imageCache[imageCounter] = swappedImage;
            imageCounter++;
 });
        //start slide show
 imageCounter = 0;
        var nextImage;
        setInterval( function() {
            $("#caption").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#image").fadeOut(1000,
                    function() {
                        imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
                        nextImage = imageCache[imageCounter];
                        $("#caption").text(nextImage.title).fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                    );
        },
        3000);
 // set up event handlers for links (given line)  
 $("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {
            imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
            nextImage = imageCache[imageCounter];
            
                //given two lines
  var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
  fadeIn(1000);
                //given two lines
  var caption = $(this).attr("title");
  $("#caption").text(caption);
                fadeIn(1000);
            // cancel the default action of the link (given line)
     evt.preventDefault();
 }); // end click
 // move focus to first thumbnail (given line)
 $("li:first-child a").focus();
}); // end ready
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
     <ul id="image_list">
         <li><a href="images/h1.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-1">
          <img src="thumbnails/t1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="images/h2.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-2">
          <img src="thumbnails/t2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="images/h3.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-3">
          <img src="thumbnails/t3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="images/h4.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-4">
          <img src="thumbnails/t4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="images/h5.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-5">
          <img src="thumbnails/t5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
         <li><a href="images/h6.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-6">
          <img src="thumbnails/t6.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
     </ul>
     <h2 id="caption">James Allison: 1-1</h2>               
     <p><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="image"></p>
 </main>
```

Comment: did you see the error message that it throws when executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `});` (which is closing `$(document).ready(function() {`) after the `setInterval(..., 3000);`, at line 25.

These lines:

```
    3000);
    });    // remove
```

A working version:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // preload images(given three lines)
  var swappedImage, imageCounter = 0,
    imageCache = [];
  $("#image_list a").each(function() {
    swappedImage = new Image();
    swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
    swappedImage.title = $(this).attr("title");
    imageCache[imageCounter] = swappedImage;
    imageCounter++;
  });
  //start slide show
  imageCounter = 0;
  var nextImage;
  setInterval(function() {
      $("#caption").fadeOut(1000);
      $("#image").fadeOut(1000,
        function() {
          imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
          nextImage = imageCache[imageCounter];
          $("#caption").text(nextImage.title).fadeIn(1000);
        }
      );
    },
    3000);
 
  // set up event handlers for links (given line)  
  $("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {
    imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
    nextImage = imageCache[imageCounter];
  
    //given two lines
    var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
    fadeIn(1000);
    //given two lines
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#caption").text(caption);
    fadeIn(1000);
    // cancel the default action of the link (given line)
    evt.preventDefault();
  }); // end click
  // move focus to first thumbnail (given line)
  $("li:first-child a").focus();
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
  <ul id="image_list">
    <li>
      <a href="images/h1.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-1">
        <img src="thumbnails/t1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h2.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-2">
        <img src="thumbnails/t2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h3.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-3">
        <img src="thumbnails/t3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h4.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-4">
        <img src="thumbnails/t4.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h5.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-5">
        <img src="thumbnails/t5.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h6.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-6">
        <img src="thumbnails/t6.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="caption">James Allison: 1-1</h2>
  <p><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="image"></p>
</main>
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Thanks!!! There is just one issue now. My images are disappearing after the first one, but the titles are fading in and out appropriately.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can test it.